# NULL typing in BigQuery CTEs

Tags: google-bigquery, common-table-expression, typing

I want to execute a merge statement in BigQuery which fills missing fields coming from late data of an upstream data pipeline. For this, I dynamically create the SQL merge statement using a CTE. Since it is late data, I know that the target table already has a partially filled row. So when creating the dynamic SQL merge statement I utilize this information to only update the missing fields by setting the already present fields in the CTE as NULL, using `T.already_filled_col= IFNULL(S.already_filled_col, T.already_filled_col)`, where `S.already_filled_col` is NULL.

However, since it is a CTE without a schema, BigQuery complains that the NULL value in the CTE is of the wrong type. In particular, I get the error

> **No matching signature for function IFNULL for argument types: INT64, STRING**

How do I specify the type of the NULL value in a CTE?

Below is a minimal working example

Given a target table with the following schema

```
[
    {
        "name": "join_col",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "already_filled_col",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "update_col",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    }
]
```

Fill it with dummy data:

```
INSERT `my_project.my_dataset.test_table` (join_col, already_filled_col, update_col)
VALUES
('join_key', 'on_time_data', NULL)
```

My merge statement:

```
MERGE `my_project.my_dataset.test_table` AS T
USING (
    SELECT
        "join_key" AS join_col,
        NULL AS already_filled_col,
        "late_data" AS update_col
) AS S
ON T.join_col= S.join_col
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
   T.already_filled_col= IFNULL(S.already_filled_col, T.already_filled_col),
   T.update_col= IFNULL(S.update_col, T.update_col)
```

I am aware that I could replace `NULL AS already_filled_col` in the CTE with `CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS already_filled_col`. However, I am hoping that there is an easier way, since for the actual data the types are not always STRING and deriving them dynamically is something I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: If you want to use NULL values inside CTE, you need to CAST the null values like this example: “cast(null as varchar(100))”. Another way is to use IFNULL.

Comment: I am aware of the CAST (see original question), could you explain the use of IFNULL when creating the CTE (in particular the `already_fille_col` column)?

Comment: You can use the [IFNULL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#ifnull) statement in the CTE to validate; if the result is null, you can insert another value. You can use it in the select statement or where statement; you can follow this sintaxis: SELECT IFNULL(NULL, 0) as a result. Or you can try [NULLIF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#nullif) in this case if both expressions are equal and return null if they don’t return the expression.

Comment: Thanks! Though I don't see how that helps me in my case. I want to specifically enter `NULL` as value of a column within the CTE.

Comment: This is the only way "cast(null as varchar(100))" to insert the NULL values inside the CTE or use [Cloud Run actions on BigQuery events](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-trigger-cloud-run-actions-bigquery-events). You can use insert data and Cloud Run will automatically fill the column that you want with NULL.